# How does a memory managemet unit map a virtual address to a physical address

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual-address-space

If a computer system has a main memory of `1mb` and virtual address space of `16mb` while the disk block size is `1kb`. How does the memory management unit map a virtual address to a physical address?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you intend to ask "how does MMU maps virtual memory to physical memory" (as in your question description).

To start off, virtual memory is managed by operating systems. MMU only provides hardware mechanism to take advantage of it.

Operating systems will keep a map of virtual_address -> physical_address for each individual process.

For example if a program uses virtual page [0, 1, 2, 3], operating systems can map these pages to physical pages as [64, 128, 256, 512].

Since the virtual address space is larger than physical address space, not all of the virtual memory will be mapped to physical memory at any moment if physical memory cannot hold all of them. Therefore, some of the data would be swapped out to disk, and thus not present in physical memory.

For example, let's simplify your case by assuming that the virtual memory has 8 pages, but the physical memory can only hold 4 pages of data. If the process has data on virtual page [0,1,2,3,4], apparently physical memory cannot hold all 5 pages. Therefore one of the virtual pages will be put in disk, and the memory mappings of system will be something like [0->2, 1->1, 2->3, 4->0], and in this case virtual page 3 will be swapped out in disk.

[image]

Those swapped out pages will only be brought back to main memory by OS if the program needs the data, and one of the pages previously present in main memory needs to be swapped out to make space. Algorithms to determine which page to swap out is another topic (for example, LRU, clock algorithm).

In reality the memory system is more complicated than this scenario, because modern operating systems allow multiple processes running in the system, and OS itself uses other techniques (setting threshold to trigger page swapping, for example) to make memory system more efficient.

Comment: Okay, I'm following, i don't know if you can explain that in a diagram.

Comment: I just added a picture to illustrate the example.

Answer (score 0):

The memory management using translates LOGICAL addresses to PHYSICAL addresses.

It does that translation using PAGE TABLE defined by the operating system. The format of page tables varies with systems and there are at least three major approaches processors take to define them. Generally, a processor with have one or more privileged registers that point to the page tables for the current process. These registers are normally loaded as part of the context change that brings in a new process.

In the simple case a page table is just an array that contains the mapping between logical and physical address. Some number of high order bits of an address serve as an index into the page table. The corresponding page table entry specifies the physical page frame the logical page is mapped to.

Some number of low order bits of the addressserve as the offset into the physical page frame.

The operating system maintains the page tables in the format the MMU expects them to be in. The MMU does the translation between logical addresses an physical addresses transparently.

The disk block size is irrelevant to this translation.